# Boost.Spirit with Boost.Variant and C++11: Expecting a zero-argument constructor

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-spirit, boost-variant

I'm trying to compile a simple grammar using Boost.Spirit. I'm using g++ 4.7.0 and boost 1.49.0-1.1 on Arch Linux x86_64.

The eventual goal here is an assembler. There will be multiple operands with one class each. All the operand types together are stored in a `boost::variant` type.

I've had success compiling this sample up to the `direct` rule when it is also the base_type of the grammar, but introducing the `operand` rule (and making it the base type) causes g++ 4.7.0 to complain that:

```
example.cpp:61:7:   required from ‘Grammar<Iterator>::Grammar() [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >]’
example.cpp:76:21:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:23:63: error: no matching function for call to ‘DirectOperand::DirectOperand()’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/attributes.hpp:23:63: note: candidates are:
example.cpp:20:12: note: DirectOperand::DirectOperand(const DirectValue&)
example.cpp:20:12: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
example.cpp:16:7: note: DirectOperand::DirectOperand(const DirectOperand&)
example.cpp:16:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't understand why it should be looking for a default constructor for `DirectOperand`, since the semantic action should call it with the constructor.

I've tried lots of variations, including

```
operand = directOp[_val = _1];
```

and even writing a helper function to "force" the type, like:

```
static Operand makeDirectOperand( const DirectOperand& op ) { return op; }

// ...

operand = directOp[&makeDirectOp];
```

but no matter what I do, it complains about the missing default constructor.

<strike>When I actually defined a zero-argument constructor, I found that it compiled, but that that `DirectOperand::value_` never changed from the default value I assigned.</strike>

Here's the code. It's as short as I could make it.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_uint.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

typedef std::uint16_t DataWord;
typedef boost::variant<std::string, DataWord> DirectValue;

class DirectOperand {
private:
  DirectValue value_;
public:
  explicit DirectOperand( const DirectValue& value ) :
  value_( value ) {}

  const DirectValue& value() const { return value_; }
};

// For example purposes, but there will be multiple operand types
// here.
typedef boost::variant<DirectOperand> Operand;

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct Grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, Operand(), ascii::space_type> {
   Grammar() : Grammar::base_type( operand ) {
      using qi::lexeme;
      using ascii::char_;
      using qi::uint_parser;
      using namespace qi::labels;

      uint_parser<DataWord, 16, 1, 4> uhex_p;
      uint_parser<DataWord, 10, 1, 5> uint_p;

      word =
        char_( "a-zA-Z._" ) [_val += _1]
        >> *char_( "a-zA-Z0-9._" ) [_val += _1]
        ;

      number = (
        "0x" >> uhex_p
        | uint_p
        )
        [_val = _1]
        ;

      direct %= ( word | number );

      directOp %= direct;

      // This would be ( directOp | indirectOp | etc)
      operand %= directOp;
   }

  qi::rule<Iterator, DataWord(), ascii::space_type> number;
  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> word;
  qi::rule<Iterator, DirectValue(), ascii::space_type> direct;
  qi::rule<Iterator, DirectOperand(), ascii::space_type> directOp;
  qi::rule<Iterator, Operand(), ascii::space_type> operand;
};

int main() {
   std::string line;

   typedef std::string::iterator iterator_type;
   typedef Grammar<iterator_type> Grammar;
   Grammar grammar {};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the instantiation of the attribute `qi::rule` (`directOp` here) requires a default constructor.

If you are loathe to include a default constructor in `DirectOperand`, you could try wrapping it up in a `boost::optional` for the purpose of deferring initialization.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Boost.Optional solved the problem nicely. My comment in my question about garbage when the default constructor was called was actually due to lack of debugging symbols.

Comment: The 'optional' seems not working with x3 in some cases. Could you please explain what exactly dereferences optionals in Qi?

Comment: @IgorR.: Sorry, but I haven't worked with Qi for... close to 5 years now, so I have no idea :(

Comment: @sehe perhaps you could sched some light?

Comment: @IgorR. It's the `move_to` and other traits in `boost::spirit::x3`. If you have a specific case where "it's not working" I might be able to explain it or confirm a bug

Comment: @sehe sorry, even more trivial: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9Vsk4ZLJruy3T9k2 (in Qi optional<T> attr used to get dereferenced somehow, didn't it?)